# Regex works in terminal but not in Perl script

Tags: regex, perl, text

This is related to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/how-can-you-combine-all-lines-that-end-with-a-backslash-character?newreg=193b270469d14470908299ea03c589dc)

Where combination of all lines that end with a backslash character is done. The following Perl command works in terminal but not in Perl script:

```
perl -i -p -e 's/\\\n//' input_file
```

In Perl script, I set it this way but it does not work:

```
`perl -i -p -e 's/\\\n//' $input_file_path_variable`;
```

**Updated the file content and code used

Input file content as follows:

```
foo bar \
bash \
baz
dude \
happy
```

Desired output content:

```
foo bar bash baz
dude happy
```

Current script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

use Getopt::Long;
use FindBin;
use File::Path;
use File::Copy;
use DirHandle;
use FileHandle;
use File::Basename;
use Env;
use File::Slurp;

my $dummy_file = "/wdir/dummy.txt";
my $file_content = read_file($dummy_file);
print "$file_content\n";
print "==============================================\n"

my $ttest = $file_content =~ s/\\\n//;
print "$ttest\n";
```

Current Output

```
foo bar \
bash \
baz
dude \
happy
==============================================
1
```

Comment: Backticks act as double-quoted string literals, and `\\ ` becomes `\ ` in double-quoted string literals. /// Also, you have a code injection bug. That's not the proper way to create a shell command. See String::ShellQuote. /// Finally, why are you using backticks for a program that produces no output to STDOUT? You could avoid having to use String::ShellQuote by using the multi-argument form of `system`.

Comment: @tobyink Yes, may I know the correct way to do this? I tried reading the whole file into a variable and applied Oliver's answer but unable to get desired output.

Comment: Show us your code, the input you are using, and a demonstration of how it is not working.

Comment: @TLP My bad on that, I have updated the question with the input used. You are right on your assumption and your answer fixed my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @tobyink Point taken on not using a Perl one liner in backticks within another Perl script, I have no clue that this is a bad idea. Thought this is the fastest way to do what I want and change the content of the input file.

Comment: Add a /g to the end of this "my $ttest = $file_content =~ s/\\\n//;" . it's currently only matching the first and thinking it's completed. the /g at the end will replace all matches

Comment: @jwen - You might also want a `/r` at the end of that last regex, if you want `$ttest` to contain the result of the replacement.

Also, give [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path%3A%3ATiny) a look -- not applicable to this problem, just a thought.

Comment: @jwen Note that in your output, you have a trailing `1`. In case you are wondering what that is, it is the return value from the substitution, and the value in `$ttest`. You may be thinking that it should contain the altered string from `$file_content`, but this is not the case. It contains the return value from `s///`, which in this case is `1` for success. If you DO want to return the altered string (and keep the original unchanged), you can use the `/r` modifier, e.g. `my $ttest = $str =~ s///rg`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I realized what your problem is. You need to make your substitution match multiple times.

You are working with this one-liner:

```
perl -i -p -e 's/\\\n//' input_file
```

Which will replace the backslash and newline *once per line* in a file read in line-by-line mode. And now you are trying to implement it inside another program, where you are slurping a whole file into a variable, as mentioned in your comment on another answer:

> I tried reading the whole file into a variable and applied your solution, not working for me: my $file_content = read_file($input_file_path_variable) and then $file_content =~ s/\\n//;

This will only replace one time. The first match in the file. You need to add the modifier `/g` to make the match global, as many times as possible:

```
$file_content =~ s/\\\n//g;
```

I am not sure how you are using your code, since you are not showing us. This makes answering simple questions hard. But if my assumptions are correct, this will fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've changed your code/approach at least once since originally asking the question, but based on your current code, your issue is this line:

```
my $ttest = $file_content =~ s/\\\n//;
```

Firstly, the `s///` operator needs a `g` at the end so that it's a global search and replace, instead of stopping after the first substitution.

Secondly, `$file_content =~ s/\\\n//` doesn't *return* the final string; it modifies the string in-place. (So it's changing `$file_content`.) In recent versions of Perl, you can add an `r` modifier to the end to get it to return the modified string.

So either of these will work for you:

```
my $ttest = ( $file_content =~ s/\\\n//gr );
```

Or:

```
( my $ttest = $file_content ) =~ s/\\\n//g;
```

Full script which produces the output you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp;

my $file_content = read_file('/tmp/dummy.txt');

(my $ttest = $file_content) =~ s/\\\n//g;

print "$file_content\n";
print "==============================================\n";
print "$ttest\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

In a Perl you should write:

```
$input_file_variable =~ s/\\\n//;
```